# Javascript forEach as special variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am trying to understand the code of radial progress bar made using svg here but i am not able to understand the var forEach used here in following part.
is it some specialy defined variable because it is not working if we replace it with other variable like temp etc. and also please explain the source of parameters passed into the function.

```
var forEach = function (array, callback, scope) {
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     callback.call(scope, i, array[i]);
     }}
```

here is the complete code: 
help will be appreciated :)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

        var con = "<div class='center'></div>";
        $("body").prepend(con);
           var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");

             svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '200px');
             svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '280px');
             svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', 'progress');
             svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'data-progress', '65');
             $('.center').prepend(svg);

             var path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
             path.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', 'fill');
             path.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', 'M5,40a35,35 0 1,0 70,0a35,35 0 1,0 -70,0');
             $("svg").prepend(path);

             var spath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
             spath.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', 'track');
             spath.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', 'M5,40a35,35 0 1,0 70,0a35,35 0 1,0 -70,0');
             $("svg").prepend(spath);

             var forEach = function (array, callback, scope) {
                  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    callback.call(scope, i, array[i]);
                 }}
     window.onload = function(){
       var max = -219.99078369140625;
       forEach(document.querySelectorAll('.progress'), function (index,value){
       percent = value.getAttribute('data-progress');
       value.querySelector('.fill').setAttribute('style',
       'stroke-dashoffset: ' + ((100 - percent) / 100) * max);});}})
 </script>
```

Comment: Yes, someone made their own `forEach` function, that seems to work similar to the native [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function, only it accepts anything with a length, including NodeLists. It's just a function like any other function ?

Comment: Replacing `forEach` with any other name, like `temp`, isn't an issue at all, it's not "special" in any way -> https://jsfiddle.net/no9mdLsp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var forEach`

Here we define a variable that holds a reference to a function.

`function(array, callback, scope)`

The function accepts three parameters:

- array: An Array that we can iterate through.
- callback: A reference to a function.
- scope: The scope that will be used to run callback (This defines the 'this' inside callback).

`for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`

Just a for loop.

`callback.call(scope, i, array[i])`

call() is a method of the Function type and it's equivalent to just calling the function, like doing callback(), but with the added benefit of letting you run the function on a particular scope. i.e:

```
var f = function(){
    console.log("Hi, " + this.name);
};
var scope1 = {name: "John"};
var scope2 = {name: "Peter"};
f.call(scope1);// logs Hi, John
f.call(scope2);// logs Hi, Peter
```

The other two call() arguments are passed as parameters to the function.

Hope that clarifies how the source parameters work.

Answer (score 2):

Keep two things in mind:

1. In JavaScript, functions are data. This means they can be assigned as the value of a variable, just like any other data can be. But, because they are functions, you have two ways to interact with that data:

   1a. As data:

   ```
    var x = function(){alert("test");};
    var y = x;
   ```

   1b. As invokable code:

   ```
    x(); // runs the function stored in x
   ```
2. Property names can be hidden in a smaller scope.  `forEach` is the name of a property that the `Array.prototype` object has, but property names can be overridden causing the identifier (property name) to take on a different meaning for a given scope.  In your case, `forEach` isn't actually hiding the `forEach` of `Array.prototype` because it's not being assigned as a property name of that object, but it is just a regular variable that holds function data and that makes it callable.

Comment: thanks bro. i got your point but i have still one more doubt regarding the 3rd parameter ie. scope here which is not being used in the foreach data.

Comment: The forEach funciton that you show is just another way to do what the Array.forEach does. The 3rd argument allows for an object reference to be passed in as the scope object (`this`) for the function. The fact that it didn't get used is no big deal. The function just allows for it. Remember, all arguments in JavaScript are optional.